# list of list, I need to go in pairs to find common elements in each pair of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, grouping

I have a list of arrays, from my list of arrays. They are in one variable, I just did

This is my variable  `

```
 (formatted numbers)`=    
[['3' '4' '7' '18' '24' '27' '26' '41' '43' '45' '47' '48' '51' '52' '54' '55' '59' '60' '61' '70']
 ['1' '2' '8' '17' '23' '31' '37' '40' '41' '42' '50' '52' '53' '55' '59' '67' '69' '74' '76' '79']
 ['6' '7' '10' '11' '14' '22' '23' '39' '46' '48' '49' '50' '52' '54' '59' '60' '61' '64' '78' '80']
 ['2' '5' '7' '11' '12' '13' '17' '22' '27' '31' '46' '51' '54' '55' '58' '63' '70' '71' '75' '77']
 ['6' '7' '8' '11' '15' '17' '22' '25' '35' '51' '57' '58' '59' '60' '72' '74' '76' '79' '80' None]
 ['1' '2' '3' '9' '20' '25' '26' '29' '31' '33' '35' '38' '42' '45' '48' '52' '55' '74' '77' '78']
 ['1' '6' '12' '14' '15' '16' '17' '20' '23' '29' '33' '37' '40' '43' '47' '52' '60' '66' '68' '73']
 ['3' '4' '8' '14' '15' '16' '24' '27' '28' '41' '43' '47' '49' '50' '54' '57' '65' '73' '74' '77']]
desired output = 7,11 show up 3 times in indices [2,3,4]




But I am looking to see if there are numbers that show up together. For example: 7 and 11 show up together in the 3rd,4th,and 5th. 

This is what I have tried.
`common = []


for value in range (len(formatted_numpy_numbers_to_dict)):
    for key in formatted_numpy_numbers_to_dict[0]:
        if key in formatted_numpy_numbers_to_dict[4]:
            common = []
            for val in formatted_numpy_numbers_to_dict[0]:
                if val in formatted_numpy_numbers_to_dict[4]:
                    common.append(val)`
and this gives 
the dicts after intersection: ['3', '18', '43', '54']
```

This works if I want to go and put the indices in one by one, but that's not what we do in programing, right?

but I don't know where to even start to have a function or script do it. I know this isn't a code farm, and any guidance would be great. The list has about 800 lists, and has 20 values per array. They are dtype=object, I don't need it to be. I think a dictionary with the occurrence of the groups as the key and the groups of numbers as the values would work. The formatted_numpy_numbers = the list of arrays. The list of arrays in the question is just a snippet of the formatted_numpy_numbers. So, the shape = (900, 20), They are a dtype object, the number of occurrences and the groups of numbers is what I am looking for in the end. Thank you, and have a good one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. At first you need to describe better what `formatted_numpy_numbers` looks like. For instance, you could provide the outputs of commands like `formatted_numpy_numbers`, `formatted_numpy_numbers.shape`, `formatted_numpy_numbers.dtype`. You are also expected to be more specific on your expected output. I guess you're working with `object` data type of `shape = (8, 20)`, isn't it? And I guess also that you want to find ids of rows where specific number is met, like so: `{1: [1, 5, 6], 2: [1, 3, 5], ...}`. Just try to define better what you want to achieve.

Comment: You might like to flatten your array using command [`np.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and then count occurences of each value 1 - 80 with [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) but I'm not sure if you're good with it.

Comment: I wasn't quite finished but was on my phone typing it out. The list has about 800 lists, and has 20 values per array. They are dtype=object, I don't need it to be. I think a dictionary with the occurrence of the groups as the key and the groups of numbers as the values would work. The formatted_numpy_numbers = the list of arrays. The list of arrays in the question is just a snippet of the formatted_numpy_numbers. So, the shape = (800, 20), They are a dtype object, and a dictionary of the occurrences as the key and the groups of numbers as the values, is what I am looking for in the end.

Comment: Alright but you should write what you're looking for in your question, not in comments. Fortunately, it's clear what you try to achieve anyway.

Comment: I can get the value counts, for each value. Im looking to see if groups of numbers show in the data, and how many times. but thank you for the idea on np.bincount.